# Grails gsp: count of auto-number in list

Tags: grails, gsp

How do I get a count (auto-number) inside of an each loop in a gsp (groovy server page)?  I'm doing a project of FAQ's.  The following code works just fine, but I'd would like to number each question in the output like:

1. FAQ question here...

  Answer here....

2,  FAQ question here...

  Answer here....

```
<g:each in="${gFaqCategory.list()}" var="faqCategory">
<p><b>${faqCategory.categoryType}</b></p>

<g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" var="faq">
                                        <li><p>${faq.question}</p></li> 
                                        <li><p>${faq.answer} </li></p>
                                    </g:each>
                            </g:each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" var="faq" status="i">
    <li><p>${i+1}. ${faq.question}</p></li> 
    <li><p>${faq.answer} </li></p>
</g:each>
```

Use [`status`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html) in `g:each`. Strongly suggest to go through the doc.

Comment: @dmahapatro, I'm just curious: this variable is incremented automatically. What will be the result if you increment it manually? I mean ++i. Seems that we may end up with 1, 3, 5, 7 etc. :)

Comment: @PawełPiecyk correct. I had it `i+1` before editing to `++i`. Bad thing to do if multitasking. :). Thanks for rectifying.